# Loading Spin and Disable button in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, jquery

I have this function which is called after the button was clicked, I would like to disable the button until the alert comes up and to show a Loading Spin while it is not finished processing the feed. This is my function code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

function generateFeed(feedId) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/index/generate/') ?>", 
        method: 'GET', 
        data: {FeedId : feedId}
    }).success(function() {
        alert ('Generation Successful!');
    }).error(function() {
        alert ('Generation Failed!');
    });

}
```

And the button is this:

```
$block->addButton('Generate', array(
'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Generate Feed'),
'onclick'   => "generateFeed(" . $blockID . ")",
'class'     => 'go',
'index' => 'generate',
'name' => 'generate'
), -1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Js function to:

```
function generateFeed(feedId, buttonId) {
    jQuery("#"+buttonId).attr('disabled', 'disabled');    
    jQuery("#"+buttonId).addClass('disabled');
    jQuery("#loading-mask").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/index/generate/') ?>", 
        method: 'GET', 
        data: {FeedId : feedId}
    }).success(function() {
        alert ('Generation Successful!');
        jQuery("#"+buttonId).attr('disabled', 'false');
        jQuery("#"+buttonId).removeClass('disabled');
        jQuery("#loading-mask").hide();
    }).error(function() {
        alert ('Generation Failed!');
        jQuery("#"+buttonId).attr('disabled', 'false');
        jQuery("#"+buttonId).removeClass('disabled');
        jQuery("#loading-mask").hide();
    });

}
```

Change button to:

```
$block->addButton('Generate', array(
'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Generate Feed'),
'onclick'   => "generateFeed(" . $blockID . ", this.id)",
'class'     => 'go',
'index' => 'generate',
'name' => 'generate'
), -1);
```